# Java servlet equivalent of command line PHP?

Tags: java, servlets

Is there an equivalent of [command line PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) for Java servlets?

Comment: Not directly. What's the functional requirement then? Unit testing?

Comment: In Java, there is usually another way to do whatever you need to run this way. i.e. it supports it but you don't want to go there.

Comment: I just wanted a simple way to eyeball the HTML it generates.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would create a dedicated package for the business logic portion of your application, that way both a servlet and Java command line application can import the functionality. If you separate them well enough it will also vastly reduce maintenance etc.